# Python can't import module in subdirectory

Tags: python

I am trying to reorganize the code of one of my projects for better understanding and while doing so I got an error with the imports when I attempt to import a module that is in from second level folder.
I have the following folder structure:

```
src
  managements  
    __init__.py  
    azureManagement.py  
    azuredevops  
      __init__.py  
      coreManagement.py  
  main.py
```

and my main.py file looks like:

```
from managements.azureManagement import Management as Azure
from managements.azuredevops.coreManagement import Management as AzureDevOpsCore
...
```

The first import works fine, however the second one throws the following error

> No module named 'managements.azuredevops.coreManagement'

I can import everything that is a **src** folder level or in 1st level folders Ex: **src\managements**, but if a I have a second level folder Ex: **src\managements\azuredevops** I can't import anything from them.

Do you know where can be the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `from managements.azureDevOps.coreManagement import Management as AzureDevOpsCore`?

Comment: It was a typo on the post, I just correct it. The folder is azuredevops in lowercase.